# Make eclipse ignore all errors in current project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have loaded an eclipse project . It has a bunch of errors related to undefined imports . I dont really care for these imports . They are from a third party which i will not be able to fix at the moment . I just want to browse the code without the **RED** symbols in the source code .

Is it possible to set error check off ONLY for this project and not for other projects loaded into eclipse and also not for future ones that i will load ?

Comment: consider upgrading to maven for building your project... this will reduce your work drastically for imports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please close all the remaining projects and look in to `problems`.So that you will get only  the open project `errors.`

Before starting please add required jar(it may be maven also).So that it will be very easy.

Not recommended, But if you dont want to see the error lines

**UPDATE:**

**Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations->Errors->Un check all.**

Comment: I dont have those jar files . So there is no way to fix these errors . I just want to avoid seeing the red marks as they kinda are distracting .

Comment: Updated.Please have a look.

Comment: i kinda wanted a per project solution but then i guess for the time being i shall close all my current projects . Hopefully before moving on to my next project i shall remember to switch these ON !!

Comment: @rockstar yeah.Please do not forget :P

Answer (score 0):

This isn't for the "current project" (per the exact question), but it is applicable in a more general sense...

**Just close the project!**

This should be obvious, but it went right over my head at first.  I had no idea the project was "open" by default just because it was "imported".  The ui in Eclipse should be tweaked at bit to make this more clear.  Apparently, unless you realized this, all of those projects you see listed are "open" by Eclipse and therefore part of whatever processing it is doing, including listing errors (even when you switch "working sets", etc).

To be explicit, in the project explorer, right-click on that project making a mess of your errors list and lighting up with an nasty "!" on it, then select "close project".  When you want to work on it again, simply right click on it and select "open project".

If you have a working set selected, which it belongs to, it will disappear entirely when you close it.  Deselecting all working sets, gives you the entire list of projects that Eclipse knows about. In this view, you'll see how the icon on the project changes to denote being open vs closed.